# Union type from two generic interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am in the way of learning typescript. And fell into the problem of syntax of union type, one of them is a *generic* interface:

```js
interface ArrayElementError {
  kind: 'failure'
  reason: string
}

interface ArrayElementSuccess<T> {
  kind: 'success'
  value: T
}

type ArrayElement = ArrayElementError | ArrayElementSuccess
// or interface ArrayElement<T extends ArrayEmementError | ArrayElementSuccess> {}
```

The code above was not compiled and got the error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
```

What is correct syntax to extends from two generic interfaces (or create a new type using type keyword)?

Comment: Are you just looking to make `ArrayElement` generic as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOlyEN)?  If so I could write up an answer (but it seems almost like a typo); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes that what I need. Pretty sure that I've tried this code snippet from playground, but it won't compile. Probably due to some typo issue. Just curious, can we avoid `type` keyword (use interface instead) when define ArrayElement?

Comment: So what should we do here?  Should I write an answer or do you want to close the question as caused by a typo?

Comment: @jcalz please write an answer, it's no so many matches in a search engine with the similar request. Maybe it's useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you want is probably:

```
type ArrayElement<T> = ArrayElementError | ArrayElementSuccess<T>;
```

where `ArrayElement` is itself [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `T` which can be passed as the type argument to `ArrayElementSuccess`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngUQDYQC2E4OGA9lMgN4BQyyA1qACYBcyA5PMHgK5QIneskFwAzuRAdxYKKADmtAL61aoSLEQp0mXAWLgAynwRJx4gDwAVAHw0RzEOy7jT58cIYA3OPwgc1ipqYFgADjoY2PhEJGA29gC8aFH6saQUVAA+KXoxhmAmZhAWCQDcQA)